# Submitting a Comment form in Product Page not working

Tags: python, django

I am trying to add a comment section in products page, I am now trying to test the template to see if it directing correctly

After I press the submit button nothing is happening it doesnt return any errors

Here is the Models.py

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="ItemComments")
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    comment = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return '{} by {}'.format(self.subject, str(self.user.username))

class CommentForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = ['subject', 'comment']
```

here is the urls

```
app_name = 'core'

urlpatterns = [
    path('', HomeView.as_view(), name='home'),
    path('<slug>/addcomment/', views.addcomment, name='addcomment'),
```

Here is the views

```
def addcomment(request):
    return HttpResponse("My product Page")
```

Here is the template

```
                <form class="review-form" action={% url 'core:addcomment' item.slug %} method= "post">
                {% csrf_token %}

                  <div class="md-form md-outline">
                    <input name="subject" type="text" id="form75" class="form-control pr-6">
                    <label for="form75">Your Subject</label>
                  </div>

                  <div class="md-form md-outline">
                    <textarea name="comment" id="form76" class="md-textarea form-control pr-6" rows="4"></textarea>
                    <label for="form76">Your review</label>
                  </div>
                    {% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
                  <div class="text-right pb-2">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary waves-effect waves-light">Add a review</button>
                  </div>
                    {% else %}
                    You must be Logged in to Comment
                    {% endif %}
                </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't actually a submit button in the form. Try changing the button type to `submit` like this -

`<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary waves-effect waves-light">Add a review</button>`

Answer (score 0):

```
<form class="review-form" action={% url 'core:addcomment' item.slug %} method= "post">
                {% csrf_token %}

                  <div class="md-form md-outline">
                    <input name="subject" type="text" id="form75" class="form-control pr-6">
                    <label for="form75">Your Subject</label>
                  </div>

                  <div class="md-form md-outline">
                    <textarea name="comment" id="form76" class="md-textarea form-control pr-6" rows="4"></textarea>
                    <label for="form76">Your review</label>
                  </div>
                    {% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
                  <div class="text-right pb-2">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary waves-effect waves-light">Add a review</button>
                  </div>
                    {% else %}
                    You must be Logged in to Comment
                    {% endif %}
                </form>
```